# Activity tab goes to error page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page

When I try to access [the activity tab ("All actions") in my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica?tab=activity&sort=all), nothing loads for a while, then I get a generic "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error page.

This only happens on Stack Overflow - trying the same thing on other Stack Exchange sites or on Meta Stack Overflow works fine. Other tabs also work fine.

Comment: Same here, ``Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()``

Comment: Reproducible here as well. Looked like an [older bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348987/289905), but this is new, or perhaps a regression.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you still able to?

Comment: I can't reproduce this any more.

Comment: Probably a temporary outage, then, or a bug that quickly got fixed. Marking this as no-repro.

Comment: Yes, a few minutes after my original comment, I also couldn’t reproduce it anymore.

Comment: @CodyGray: It's happening again.